# Doctrine createQueryBuilder - If Where Parameter is Empty Get All Records

Tags: php, doctrine, createquery

My Query Builder :

```
$nameParameter="david";

$query=$this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('Person\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->select("u")
            ->where("u.name = :name")
            ->setParameter('name',$nameParameter);

        return  $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

When `$nameParameter`is Empty not returned any Result;

Question : HOW Create Query That if `$nameParameter` is Empty Get All Records Of U.name Entity;

Answer (score 0):

I Find This Way :

```
$nameParameter="david";

$query=$this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('Person\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->select("u");

           if($nameParameter) {

                    $query->andWhere('u.name = :name')
                    ->setParameter('name', $nameParameter);
                }

        return  $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```